# Hoverover template Label titles change plotly python

Tags: python, hover, plotly, tooltip, plotly-python

I am trying to change the hoverover template to show Model name, Score and scaling technique, I am able to show the first two titles but I am not able to succeed in showing the third (i.e variable legend) in the tooltip Hoverover.

Below is the attached image where I am able to change the hover template of first two. I need to replace the third label Model:%{Model_Names} to be legend variable names, Could someone please help

[image]

Below is my code.

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(compareModels_aft_Cleansing, x="Base_Models", y=["Base_Models_Scores", 
                                                     "Standard_scaled_scores", "Min_Max_scaled_scores", 
                                                     "Scaling & feature selection_scores"],
              title="Training Scores", barmode='group', text = 'value',
            hover_name="Base_Models",
            hover_data={'Base_Models':False}, # remove species from hover data                     
                            )
Model_Names = ['Base_Models_Scores', 'Standard_scaled_scores', 'Min_Max_scaled_scores']
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = '%{label}: <br>Score:%{text} <br>Model: %{Model_Names}')
fig.show()
```

Please find the attached image of dataframe compareModels_aft_Cleansing below.

[image]

Comment: it would help to have\see `compareModels_aft_Cleansing`

Comment: Hi @jayveesea, Thanks for your reply, Added the Dataframe compareModels_aft_Cleansing in the question

Comment: thx for the info!  see my response below, in the example I show how you can provide your data.  It's more convenient for those trying to help to have it available right form the start in that format (a picture helps but the raw text is far more helpful) ;)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired hover text you can use the following:

```
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = '%{label}: <br>Score:%{text} <br>Model: %{data.name}<extra></extra>')
```

Couple of things to note:

1. `%{data.name}` is event data that omitted by the js backend, more info [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#hover-event).
2. The legend names were already displayed in the secondary box, to remove that use `<extra></extra>` as described [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/bar/#bar-hovertemplate).

> Anything contained in tag `<extra>` is displayed in the secondary box,
> for example `<extra>{fullData.name}</extra>`. To hide the secondary
> box completely, use an empty tag `<extra></extra>`.

Full example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Base_Models': ['SVM'], 
        'Base_Models_Scores': [.625], 
        'Scaling & feature selection_scores': [.75], 
        'Standard_scaled_scores': [.8], 
        'Min_Max_scaled_scores': [.95]}

compareModels_aft_Cleansing = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(compareModels_aft_Cleansing, x="Base_Models", y=["Base_Models_Scores", 
                                                     "Standard_scaled_scores", "Min_Max_scaled_scores", 
                                                     "Scaling & feature selection_scores"],
              title="Training Scores", barmode='group', text = 'value',
            hover_name="Base_Models",
            hover_data={'Base_Models':False}, # remove species from hover data                     
                            )

Model_Names = ['Base_Models_Scores', 'Standard_scaled_scores', 'Min_Max_scaled_scores']
fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = '%{label}: <br>Score:%{text} <br>Model: %{data.name}<extra></extra>')
fig.show()
```

[image]